# HttpTriggered Azure function throwing " No such host is known error"(xxxxxxxxxxx.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:8993)

Tags: azure, function, runtime, version, host

The host url mentioned in the error is xxxxxxx.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com:8993. How is this url formed? and where can that be changed? The actual function url has xxxxxx.domain.com, how is that redirected to xxxx.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com.

[image]